# Find XML tag which is present several times

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I am working with an Oracle database 19c.

I have a table with the blob field "MSG_BODY". This field contains XML's like that:

```
<Body xmlns = "http://www.finnova.ch/ZV/EHF/021">
<Auftrag>
    <Auftragsinformation>
        <Auftragsidentifikation>
            <AUF_LNR>987987987987</AUF_LNR>
            <APPL_ID>9999</APPL_ID>
        </Auftragsidentifikation>
        <Auftragsreferenz>
            <EXT_REF>TEST-2020082109574181</EXT_REF>
            <EXT_AUF_REF>BA18081508D86B28</EXT_AUF_REF>
            <KD_LNR_ERF>901</KD_LNR_ERF>
        </Auftragsreferenz>
    </Auftragsinformation>
    <Zahlungsliste>
        <Zahlung>
            <Identifikation>
                <ZV_ZLG_SYS_LNR>987987987987</ZV_ZLG_SYS_LNR>
                <ZV_ZLG_LNR>1</ZV_ZLG_LNR>
            </Identifikation>
            <Referenz>
                <EXT_REF>ABCD654654654</EXT_REF>
                <EXT_REF_AUF>XX-XXX 230/99999/1</EXT_REF_AUF>
                <EXT_REF_AUF_IB>BA9999988888</EXT_REF_AUF_IB>
                <ZLG_INSTR_ID>BA999988886666</ZLG_INSTR_ID>
                <MeldungsRef>
                    <MSG_TX_ID>123123123123</MSG_TX_ID>
                    <CS_ZLG_TRACK_ID>d8047b9f-a8c7-4d74-b5c7-470510240b60</CS_ZLG_TRACK_ID>
                    <CS_SWIFTGPI_SVC_ID>001</CS_SWIFTGPI_SVC_ID>
                </MeldungsRef>
                <MeldungsRef>
                    <MSG_TX_ID_DECK>xxxxxxxxxx</MSG_TX_ID_DECK>
                </MeldungsRef>
            </Referenz>
            <Mitteilung>
                <MIT_BEGxxx</MIT_BEG>
                <MIT_BEG_XML>
                    <Ustrd>xxx</Ustrd>
                </MIT_BEG_XML>
                <PURP_CD>SALA</PURP_CD>
            </Mitteilung>
        </Zahlung>
    </Zahlungsliste>
</Auftrag>
```

The tag "Zahlung" can exist multiple times and that's OK, but into the the tag "Zahlung" is the
tag "MeldungsRef". This tag should exist zero or one time for every tag "Zahlung". That's a fault shown in the XML above. I now need a query to select all rows in the table, which contains an XML, where the tag "MeldungsRef" is multiple times there. How can I do that?

Thanks for helping me!

Regards,
mablaser

Comment: Is what you ask for xml validation purposes? In this case it would be better to register xml schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a second appearance of the `MeldungsRef` node within a `Zahlung` node, so you can look directly for that. This query shows you the first and second instances of the node, using [`xmlquery()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/xquery-and-XML-DB.html#GUID-39CDBF4D-258D-4CFE-AEBF-06ECD660C08D) and specifying the appearance to find with `[1]` or `[2]`:

```
select id,
  xmlquery(
    'declare default element namespace "http://www.finnova.ch/ZV/EHF/021"; (: :)
     /Body/Auftrag/Zahlungsliste/Zahlung/Referenz/MeldungsRef[1]'
    passing xmltype(msg_body)
    returning content
  ) as first,
  xmlquery(
    'declare default element namespace "http://www.finnova.ch/ZV/EHF/021"; (: :)
     /Body/Auftrag/Zahlungsliste/Zahlung/Referenz/MeldungsRef[2]'
    passing xmltype(msg_body)
    returning content
  ) as second
from your_table;
```

You could look for the second being not-null, but it's easier to use the same XPath with [`xmlexists()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/xquery-and-XML-DB.html#GUID-46B9D31A-3A4B-4902-A8C8-E6C72E0E74B6) to test whether a second child node exists:

```
select id
from your_table
where xmlexists(
  'declare default element namespace "http://www.finnova.ch/ZV/EHF/021"; (: :)
   /Body/Auftrag/Zahlungsliste/Zahlung/Referenz/MeldungsRef[2]'
  passing xmltype(msg_body)
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=53229aa671d25e4c3063cd19a00b1fe3) with one good (single node) and one bad (multiple node) row.

---

> i receive the following error: ORA-32512: type 'xquery external variable'

As your base column is a BLOB you need to tell it which character set it's it, e.g.:

```
  passing xmltype(msg_body, nls_charset_id('UTF8'))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d17acd11bbc048d97bc1530872634407).

Comment: Many thanks for helping me! Unfortunately i receive the following error: 
ORA-32512: type 'xquery external variable' is unknown

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @mablaser - see update; it needs to know the character set for the contents of the BLOB.